# Converting a grouped continuous variable into rows in R

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have a data frame with these values dummy vales and I want to do lm regression on them. One of the variables is a grouped continuous variable as shown below

```
df <- data.frame("y" = c(10, 11, 12, 13, 14),
                 "x" = as.factor(c("100-102", "103-105", "106-108", "109-111", "112-114")))
```

I want to regress y~x, One way is to replace the x factors with their mean numeric values. This is easily done using regular expression.

Another way is to create the additional rows and expand your dataset so it looks like this

```
data.frame("y" = c(10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11......),
           "x" = c(100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105......))
```

Is there a function that will do this?

I'm thinking of first creating additional variables like x1, x2, x3 and then use reshape2 package to convert the x columns to rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `data.table` solution. This should be really fast on large `data.frame`'s as well.

```
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df, key="y")
dt[, list(x=seq(sub("-.*$", "", x), sub(".*-", "", x))),by=y]
```

If you have more columns and you don't want each combinations while splitting by column `x`, then this is the code to use:

```
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
# get all column names except "x"
key.cols <- setdiff(names(df), "x") 
# set the data.table columns to key.cols
setkeyv(dt, key.cols)
dt.out <- dt[, list(x=seq(sub("-.*$", "", x), sub(".*-", "", x))), by = key.cols]
```

This should give you what you expect.

Comment: this is an elegant and simple solution. Thanks. btw how will it scale with datasets with multiple columns. My example was a dummy dataframe. my actual dataframe has lots of numeric columns and one factor column

Comment: just one column to split but the dataset has multiple columns, so rows for all the other columns should be repeated as well along with y

Answer (score 2):

```
require(stringr)
require(foreach)

foreach(i=1:nrow(df), .combine=rbind) %do% {
  s <- as.numeric(str_extract_all(df$x[i], "[0-9]+")[[1]])
  data.frame(y=rep(df$y[i], s[2]-s[1]+1), x=seq(s[1], s[2]))  
}
```

If your `data.frame` is really big you can go along with `%dopar%`.

Comment: that was quick. not big just 2500 rows.

Comment: `%do%` and `%dopar%` are provided by `foreach` package.